# Windows Server 2016 - Is it possible to switch between the Desktop Experience and Non-Desktop Experience?

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-server

I installed Windows 2016 Server with the Desktop Experience. Is there a way to switch between the Desktop Experience and Non-Desktop Experience on-demand?

My thought is to setup everything I want with GUI then reboot and run it without the Desktop Experience overhead and just use remote desktop if I need to access the desktop.

This is something I can do with Raspberry Pi and Raspbian OS

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You would probably need to reinstall each time you wanted to switch.

When Server 2016 was in preview, Desktop Experience was a "feature", as in roles and features on Windows Server. To switch between having a feature and not having it, you could install or uninstall the feature. And you could use PowerShell scripting to do it (though it wasn't an instant switch between one state and the other, and was likely to include a reboot.) There are some examples in [this 4sysops article](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-install-the-gui-on-windows-server-2016/#install-the-gui-on-server-core)

However, since that time, further restrictions were made such that, according to a TechNet article a few years ago, you can no longer convert between one and the other after installation, and you must re-install.

The TechNet article seems to no longer be available but there is some more info about Server 2016 GUI options at https://superwidgets.wordpress.com/2016/10/29/windows-server-2016-gui-options/

It's now considered best practice to administer Windows servers using PowerShell commands rather than remote desktop. I'd recommend you spend some time getting familiar with the PowerShell commands to do the things you need with your server.